# Confidence interval on the maximum value of a sample?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, nonparametric, small-sample

Is there any test (preferably without assuming any distribution) that can give us a confidence interval on the maximum value of a (small) sample?

**context:**
I am trying to get some estimate of upper bound on a parameter which is expensive to evaluate. Also, maximum value of this parameter is much more useful compared to any other statistics such as mean and median.

Comment: I don't suppose you can assume there would be no duplicates. Then it'd be like the German Tank Problem if you could.

Comment: **It makes no sense** to refer to a confidence interval for a characteristic of a *sample* (such as its maximum), because by definition confidence intervals are about the probability law (or population) from which the sample was drawn.  Could you please clear this up by providing more specifics about your situation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I do not have much stats background to comment on the definition. To simply put my question, is there any measure using which I can comment on maximum of entire population?
German tank problem looks interesting. In my case there is a possibility of duplicates.